# ggplotly doesn't respect order of Dates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

`ggplotly` doesn't faithfully reproduce a `ggplot` because it uses the default  order of the rows in the data frame.

Consider:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
economics <- economics %>%
  arrange(desc(unemploy))
my_plot <- ggplot(economics, aes(x = date, y = unemploy)) + 
  geom_point()
my_plot
```

The rows are re-arranged, but `ggplot` is smart enough to plot the points in the order specified by the `x` aesthetic (i.e. the date)

But `ggplotly` puts them in the order in which they appear in the data frame.

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(my_plot)
```

Is there a way to get `ggplotly` to respect the date ordering?

MORE INFO:

I am using `plotly_2.0.16` and `ggplot2_2.1.0`. I wonder if this is a result of the recent updates to both packages?

**SOLVED**:

Updating `plotly` to version 3.1.0 via GitHub (not CRAN) solved the problem.

Comment: You could make the dates as ordered factors. See `?ordered`

Comment: it works for me with plotly_2.0.16 and ggplot2_2.0.0

Comment: @MLavoie does it work if you update `ggplot2` to version 2.1.0?

Comment: no, now I get an error and I am not the only onehttps://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/481

Comment: The plotly package has been updated in the past few hours (v 3.1.0). Seems to work with ggplot2 v 2.1.0 (at least for me)